# Sorting changes list to integer in R

Tags: r

I have a list and when I apply sort() it changes the type to 'integer' which is not understandable to me. Help is really appreciated.

myfile.csv is a single column with values {"a","a","c","b","c","a"}

The code is as follows:

```
temp <- read.csv("myfile.csv",header=TRUE)
typeof(temp) ## prints: "list"
temp2 <- sort(temp[,1])
typeof(temp2) ## prints: "integer"
```

and now i can't refer elements in temp2 using temp2[1,] or temp2[2,] and get error

```
Error in `[.default`(temp3, 1, ) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Why don't you use `dput()` on `temp` so that we can see what you're after? As it stands, your code is not fully reproducible.

Comment: It seems your `temp` is a `data.frame` (`typeof(temp) == "list"`) but you only sorting the first column (`sort(temp[,1])`) which is (maybe) a `factor`. And a `factor` is of type `integer`. So everything is right but maybe your expectations differs.

Comment: temp is a data.frame with only 1 column. Therefore, when I check the typeof(temp), i get list. My objective is to compare consecutive row elements of the 'sorted' version of this list using temp2[1,]. I'm either doing the sorting in a wrong manner or referring to the sorted version wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command and `temp2` will be a data frame with sorted values:

```
temp2 <- temp[order(temp[ , 1]), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: this works perfectly! Thanks! However, a quick continued question here. I'm then executing { levels <- c(temp2[1,]) } why is 'levels' now again typeof 'integer' when the first entry is "a"?

Comment: @PreritAhuja Don't use `c`. It transforms the factor value to a numeric value. If you execute `levels <- temp2[1,]`, the value returned by `typeof(levels)` is indeed `"integer"` because factors are stored as numeric values with associated labels. Have a look at `labels`, e.g., `typeof(labels(temp2[1,]))`.

Answer (score 2):

`temp2 <- sort(temp[,1])` takes the first column of the data.frame `temp`, sorts it, and assigns it to `temp2`. The result is an atomic vector (possibly with additional attributes) because data.frame columns are atomic vectors (possibly with additional attributes). If you want the first element `temp2`, you can use `temp2[1]`. You should study `help("[")`.

Comment: i did this and i create a vector with three elements temp2[1],temp2[2],temp2[3] - instead of "a","a","c", I'm getting 1,2,3

Comment: Well, you have factors. Read the data in with `temp <- read.csv("myfile.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. And also have a look at `help("order")`.